# JDK 17 Foreign memory API throws exception - Method threw 'java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError' exception

Tags: java, memory, native, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm trying to execute the following code using **JDK 17.0.1**. I have ensured the JDK 17 is on the class path.

Here is the code i'm executing:

```
import jdk.incubator.foreign.MemoryAddress;
import jdk.incubator.foreign.MemoryHandles;
import jdk.incubator.foreign.MemorySegment;
import jdk.incubator.foreign.ResourceScope;


import java.lang.invoke.VarHandle;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

public class PanamaMain {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        MemoryAddress address = MemorySegment.allocateNative(4, ResourceScope.newImplicitScope()).address();

        VarHandle handle = MemoryHandles.varHandle(int.class, ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        int value = (int) handle.get(address); //This line throws the exception mentioned above.

        System.out.println("Memory Value: " + value);
    }
}
```

The cause of the exception is: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'java.lang.Object java.lang.invoke.VarHandle.get(java.lang.Object[])'

**Exception Details**
[image]

I saw some replies on a similar exception suggesting using the `java.library.path` system property but I got an error that the `java.library.path` is an invalid flag.

I would appreciate your help/tips on this issue! Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). In this case just copy-paste the whole stacktrace into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `VarHandle.get` method is expecting a `MemorySegment` (not `MemoryAddress`) and offset in bytes within the segment. The layouts of standard C types are found in `CLinker.C_XXX` so you don't need to hardcode byte size of `int` as 4.

Assuming that your PATH is correct for launching JDK17 then this should work:

```
MemorySegment segment = MemorySegment.allocateNative(CLinker.C_INT, ResourceScope.newImplicitScope());
VarHandle handle = MemoryHandles.varHandle(int.class, ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
handle.set(segment, 0, 4567);
int value = (int)handle.get(segment, 0);
System.out.println("Memory Value: " + value + " = 0x"+Integer.toHexString(value));
```

Prints:

```
Memory Value: 4567 = 0x11d7
```

In JDK17 you can also use `MemoryAccess` to set or get values from allocated `MemorySegment`. , and could change to:

```
MemorySegment segment = MemorySegment.allocateNative(CLinker.C_INT, ResourceScope.newImplicitScope());
MemoryAccess.setInt(segment, -1234);
int value = MemoryAccess.getInt(segment);
System.out.println("Memory Value: " + value + " = 0x"+Integer.toHexString(value));
```

Prints

```
Memory Value: -1234 = 0xfffffb2e
```

Note that the API has changed, so the equivalent code in JDK18+ will be different.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution!! It did work for me! I was trying to check the get method on the VarHandle, which looks like. `    public final native
    @MethodHandle.PolymorphicSignature
    @IntrinsicCandidate
    Object get(Object... args);`. I don't see implementation there! This is abstract class. Wondering how did you find out that it was expecting the MemorySegment and not the MemoryAdderss?

Comment: If you try just `handle.get(address)` it should give exception: `WrongMethodTypeException: cannot convert MethodHandle(VarHandle,MemorySegment,long)int to (VarHandle,MemoryAddress)Object`, so indicates passing a param of wrong type and also omitting the expected `,long` parameter.